# The meaning of $\rightsquigarrow$?

Tags: amsmath, arrows

Perhaps this is not the good place to ask this question. In order to write a scientific paper, I would like to use the symbol $\rightsquigarrow$ (works also with $\leadsto$ which has a clearer meaning, but not so much for me...)

I'm wondering about the usual meaning and use of this symbol.

Comment: Thanks in advance to (eventually) put this question in the right place if it doesn't fit here.

Comment: you should try Math.SE

Comment: @percuse Done ! It's there : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680786/ but the tag are stupid, since there is no latex nor ams math tag there. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the symbol for "the next step is" as explained [here](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/commerrs/#Consciousness) (last sentence of the section), and seems to be a (not so common) replacement for `=>` in `A => B => C`